# displaying the date(s) that appear the most

Tags: php, mysqli

This script returns the date on which most jokes were posted also the number of jokes.
The problem is when there are two or more dates with same number of jokes.
How do i display when that happens?

When there are two or more dates with same amount of jokes i want to echo all dates. Something like: there are more days with same amount of jokes (displays the dates) the jokes posted on each of these days is (number of joke)

```
<?php
 $page_title = 'day with most jokes';
include ('includes/header.html');
require ('mysqli_connect.php');


$q="SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS value_occurrence FROM joke GROUP BY date ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysql_error());
$row=  mysqli_fetch_row($r);


echo'day <b>' . $row[0] . '</b>is the day with most joke(s) </br>' ;
echo 'on that day there were<b> ' . $row[1] . ' <b> joke(s)';


    ?>
```

Comment: Return a limited number of rows. Fetch them all into an array. Then with some simple logic you can decide how many rows to display based on 'value_occurance'. i.e equal value or 'close' value etc.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for the hint but i couldn't make it so i will just write it as a bug in my project documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS value_occurrence, MAX(value_occurence) AS max_occ
     FROM joke
     GROUP BY date
     ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC)
WHERE value_occurence = max_occ
```

Or that:

```
SELECT date, value_occurence, MAX(value_occurence) AS max_occ FROM
    (SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS value_occurrence
     FROM joke
     GROUP BY date
     ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC) sq
WHERE value_occurence = max_occ
```

And then in the PHP code I would estimate number of lines returned and displayed dates accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried to at least print the number of rows affected but nothing. 
Anyways. thanks for trying

Comment: nope, still nothing. 
Please don't bother anymore i will just write this as a bug of my application.
Thanks for trying.

Comment: @mile: Ok, sorry I couldn't help.